# Classify all analytic functions $f$ for which $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a question from a previous prelim exam which I am having difficulty solving. It asks to classify all analytic functions $f$ on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ for which
$$f(ab) = f(a)f(b) $$
where $a,b \in \mathbb{D}$. Here's the progress I've made. Considering $f(0)$, we see that 
$$f(0)=f(0 \cdot z)=f(0)f(z) $$
which implies that either $f(z) = 1$ for all $z \in \mathbb{D}$, or $f(0)=0$. If $f(0) = 0$, the power series expansion of $f$ about $0$ shows that 
$$f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n, $$
and this is about as far as I have gotten. I should be able to say more about these functions, but I'm a bit stumped on how to do it.

Comment: So $f(z^2)=f(z)^2$?

Comment: Likewise, we could also say that either $\forall z \in \mathbb{D} \, f(z)=0$ or $f(1)=1$. I assume that the "unit disk" $\mathbb{D}$ is the set of all complex numbers with modulus less than or equal to the number one.

Comment: The test is a bit unclear on whether the unit disk is all complex numbers with modulus less than 1 or all complex numbers with modulus less than or equal to 1. This is important to the problem because equality would change how the functions interact with different roots of unity. Also, we do have that $f(z^2) = f(z)^2$.

Answer (score 5):

You're basically finished.

If $f(z)$ satisfies the conditions, then so does $$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{z^m}$$ for any $m$ such that $g$ is analytic.  If we set $m$ equal to $\min\{n \mid a_n \neq 0\}$  then your work shows that $g(z) = 1$ identically.

That is, the only such functions are $f(z) = z^m$ for some non-negative integer $m$.

Comment: +1. I had the same answer but you were faster.

Comment: @Brian Moehring Why does $g$ satisfy the same conditions as $f$? If it did, then $a_m = g(0\cdot z) = g(0) g(z) = a_m f(z)/z^m$. Why should this be true?

Comment: @Mike Note the conclusion is $f(z)=z^m$, which is why that equality should be true.  If your concern is with begging the question, then for the purposes of the proof, we can directly confirm that $g(ab) = g(a)g(b)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{D}\setminus \{0\}$ and then note it holds for all $a,b \in \mathbb{D}$ by continuity.

Comment: @BrianMoehring How does continuity show that it holds at the point $0$?

Comment: @Mike For instance, for a fixed nonzero $b \in\mathbb{D}$, $$g(0\cdot b) = \lim_{a\to 0} g(ab) = \lim_{a\to 0} g(a)g(b) = g(0)g(b)$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you for the clarification!